# Crontab not running python script on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: python, linux, cron, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a python script on Linux via WSL.

First of all I run `service --status-all` and both `atd` and `cron` are marked as `[+]`. Just to make sure that it works i typed in `crontab -e` the following:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/myname/Task_scripts/example.sh
```

This is what the script file example.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World - Generated every 2 mins" >> ~/hello1.txt
```

The file indeed runs as set every 2mins so everything fine so far.

Let's move to the Python part now. I follow the exact same process i.e. crontab with a script and cannot get it run no matter what. In specific these are the two alternatives (among the many i tried) that i expected to work but apparently do not. FYI I am using an anaconda environment.

Alternative 1:

What i have in crontab: `*/2 * * * * /home/myname/Task_scripts/email_example.sh`
How the file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/py36env/bin/python /home/myname/Production/example_email.py
```

Here are the rights in the .py file after running `chmod +x email_example.sh`:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 myname myname 99 Nov  7 21:26 email_example.sh`

Alternative 2:

Set the crontab as follows:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/myname/anaconda3/envs/py36env/bin/python /home/myname/Production/example_email.py
```

The rights on the .py are same as above.

Executing manually the:

```
/home/myname/anaconda3/envs/py36env/bin/python /home/myname/Production/example_email.py
```

runs as it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

have you make the example_email.py as an executable file?

```
chmod +x /home/myname/Production/example_email.py
```

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 myname myname 1470 Nov  8 08:00 example_email.py`

Comment: put that task to  `sudo corntab -e`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a few tries I added an export to a log file in crontab command and was able to backtrack the issue. It was a python issue and in specific PYTHONPATH which I had to insert in the first line of my crontab.

For the story, WSL works fine just like a real linux OS.

Friendly tip: always make sure to include a log file. For the beginners (including me) this can be done by the following example in crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/myname/Task_scripts/example.sh >> /home/myname/Logs/example.txt 2>&1
```

For organizational purposes created a Logs directory to collect such files.